# Remove a specific pattern in fasta sequences

Tags: python, fasta

I have a fasta file like this,

```
>IWB12626
AACTTGAGGGACGTGCAGCTAAGGGAGGACTACTATCCAGCACCGGAGAA[T/C]GACATGATGATCACAGAGATGCGGGCTGAATCTTGCCTCCGGTTTGAGCA
>IWB49383
CMGCTCATTTCTGCCGGGCTCGATAGCTGCCCTGTTCTTGAGAAGATCTC[A/G]ATTAAGGTGGAGGGCGATCTCCGGACTTGTCCGCGTCCATTTCACGGGTC
```

I need to remove square brackets "[]","/" and the nucleotide that follows this symbol "/", so basically choosing the 1st of the two variants. This is my script, but I dont know how to specify to program that I need one letter be removed after /.

```
with open('myfile.fasta') as f:
    with open('outfile.fasta', 'w') as out:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                out.write(line)
            else:
                out.write(line.translate(None, '[/a-z0-9]'))
```

my expected output,

```
>IWB12626
AACTTGAGGGACGTGCAGCTAAGGGAGGACTACTATCCAGCACCGGAGAATGACATGATGATCACAGAGATGCGGGCTGAATCTTGCCTCCGGTTTGAGCA
>IWB49383
CMGCTCATTTCTGCCGGGCTCGATAGCTGCCCTGTTCTTGAGAAGATCTCAATTAAGGTGGAGGGCGATCTCCGGACTTGTCCGCGTCCATTTCACGGGTC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) function.

```
with open('myfile.fasta') as f:
    with open('outfile.fasta', 'w') as out:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                out.write(line)
            else:
                out.write(re.sub(r'[\[\]]|/.', '', line))
```

`/.` matches  `/` and also the character following forward slash. `[\[\]]` character class which matches `[` or `]` symbols. `|` called alternation operator or logical OR operator usually used to combine two patterns. So by replacing all the matched characters with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Comment: you could use `out.write(re.sub(r'[\[\]]|/[a-zA-Z0-9]', '', line))` also.